# Pushing File into Android Device

Tags: push, android

I have developed an application which read text file. In Emulator I have push the file in 
**\Data\Data\PackageName\File.txt** and its working fine. But when I try to push file in Device its generate the error **Read Only File System**. I have try to remount directory as writable but the same error. Please help me how can I push file into device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The folder you are trying is locked on non-rooted phones i.e `no write permission` and I guess the device you are trying on is not a rooted one. since emulator is sort of developer device which is said to be rooted that's why you can push file to that location.

So depending on your requirement you have to either use Assest folder or File system storage

**Update:** How to use assest folder

```
Resources r = getResources();
AssetManager assetManager = r.getAssets();
InputStream in = assetManager.open(filename);
```

Comment: Agnihotri, where I can fine the assest folder in android file system?

Comment: Its not in file system it packged with your app just like drawables folder if you dont have it create one and put your file in it

Answer (score 1):

In practice, we can push such file in assets folder. Assets folder is there for you to put such raw files to be used inside the application.

Comment: Paresh Mayani, where I can fine the assets folder in android file system?

Comment: @Siddiqui check Saurabh's answer, he has mentioned to use assets folder. assets folder is normally coming up with every application that you create. If you dont find then add it like drawable folder.